# An Ektron form in a dropzone doesn't submit when logged out (8.0.1 SP1)

Tags: ektron

We are using Ektron 8.0.1 SP1

We have a client who wants to put up one-question forms on their homepage and change them out regularly.  We created a dropzone on the homepage and that worked perfectly for allowing them to change out the form whenever they want.  But it the form doesn't submit 100% of the time.

When the user is logged in the form will fire almost 100% of the time and appear to work fine.  When not logged in, submitting the form simply clears the form and nothing happens.   I know the form is functional because I can embed it on the page using a FormBlock and it works perfectly that way.

Is this a known bug?  Anyone else seen this behavior?

Zach

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors on a failed submission?

Comment: No JS errors.  I checked for that.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior often happens when your form content is loaded as regular content, i.e. using id= rather than ekfrm=. In 8.0 versions i dont believe the content block widget has an option to change this. I can't recall if there is a formblock widget in 8.0.1, so you may just need to duplicate the contentblock widget, and change its contentblock for a formblock.

Comment: The widget should contain an instance of each - one ContentBlock and one FormBlock - and they are toggled based on whether the parameter coming from the querystring is ekfrm (form) or id (content).